# Could not configure the build path with M1 chip

Tags: java, bash, path, environment-variables, zsh

Tried to export the path in the `.bash_profile` file

```
PATH=$PATH:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
```

Ran the file with `sh ~/.bash_profile` and restarted the terminal. But the path was not exported.

When ran the file with command

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

It is exporting the path in current shell but when restarting the bash it is gone from the path.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The default shell on newer macOS releases is `zsh`. You can't use `bash`-specific configuration files to configure `zsh`.

Maybe try `.profile`? Or consult the `zsh` man page, it should describe which configuration files are loaded and in which order.

Comment: `.zprofile` would be the `zsh` equivalent of `.bash_profile`.